# Asp.Net domain and subdomain issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subdomain

I have a website like **www.abc.com**. Now I want is that someone types like **www.a.abc.com** or **www.test.abc.com**  whatever before **abc.com**.  I want my users to redirect to **www.abc.com**

Comment: This is normally something you configure via your hosting

Comment: I have seen this Code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706155/regex-url-match-on-anything-but-www  many times and tried in aspx  but never worked for me. MVC doesn't allow me to write this

Comment: That's a DNS setting, not something you write ASP.NET code for.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure redirection in your web hosting interface. I think there must be a link called `Redirection Manager`. Please check that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a wildcard (*) A record in Microsoft's DNS, but you can create a wildcard CNAME. If all you are trying to do is direct all subdomains to a particular IP, this would work. For example, if you have an A record for www.mydomain.com, you could add a CNAME record for *.mydomain.com and point that at www.mydomain.com. The hostname in the request header will still be the subdomain, so your web app should be able to catch it and handle it if you want.

Comment: When I write www.*.abc.com r *.abc.com in the host name .
Then It gives error saying You cannot use these symbols

Comment: @user2936753, dont use www.*.abc, instead use *.abc.com (dont prepend the www)

Comment: @user2936753, You cannot create a wildcard (*) A record in Microsoft's DNS. sorry, but you can create a wildcard CNAME. If all you are trying to do is direct all subdomains to a particular IP, this would work. For example, if you have an A record for www.mydomain.com, you could add a CNAME record for *.mydomain.com and point that at www.mydomain.com. The hostname in the request header will still be the subdomain, so your web app should be able to catch it and handle it if you want.

Comment: @user2936753, Is there  any other solution to do this without DNS.
Actually I have been  doing this on local IIS.